Sum over products of Wigner $3$j symbol
Is the following sum known?
$$\sum_{l_1 l_2} \frac{ (2l_1+1) (2l_2 +1 ) }{4\pi} \begin{bmatrix} 
l_1  &l_2 & L \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$
where the sum is over all integers $l_1,l_2$. The "matrix" is the $3j$ Wigner symbol.

Why does your title say “products of wigner 3j symbol”? There is only one 3j symbol in each term of the sum.

all integers $l_1,l_2$ Do you mean all non-negative integers?

Based on numerical evaluation in Mathematica, I’m skeptical that this sum even converges.

Provide the limits and constraints on the $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ sums explicitly.

And constraints on $L$.

There is no relation involving this 3j alone in Varshalovich, so it is unlikely that this sum has a closed form expression.
